# Max number of apps in Apple App Store account?

Tags: app-store-connect

Is there a limit to the number of iOS apps that can be in a single iTunes Connect account? I have heard that there's a limit of 100 but can't find any documentation to back this up and I imagine that there are *lots* of companies that need to manage more than 100 apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I've never seen a limit to the number of apps you can have in your account, and I've seen *way* over 100. That being said, iTunes Connect isn't easy to work with at the best of times, and it gets increasingly clumsy as the number of apps grows – don't expect a pleasant experience managing them all!

Sadly, this management problem extends to Xcode as well – expect lots of provisioning profiles and archives cluttering things up if you're not careful.

Comment: That's great. Thanks very much.